# present simple or present perfect in this case

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-tense, present-simple

Shall I say

> 1. I have tried to send you the money but it **has not worked**.
> 2. I have tried to send you the money but it **does not work**.

I think first version is the best because all my essay did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use Present Perfect in the first part, using Present Perfect in the other *sounds a bit better* -- they both explain the actions that happen in the past, and now we have the results of them, and the exact timing is not important.

It is *fine* to use Present Indefinite in the second part too, the meaning *changes slightly*, though.  With

> I have tried ..., but it **does not work**.

you *make an assumption* that whatever obstacle there was that prevented the money from arriving, *is still in effect, still present*.

If you say

> I have tried ..., but it **has not worked**.

you only state that no "try" was a success, and the current condition of money's not being where you intended it to be.  The obstacle *may have been eliminated* since your last try, and there is *no way to know* except to try again.

Answer (score 0):

In American English I think "I tried to..." sounds better.

> I tried to send you the money, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the time reference:
if it's something that has *just* happened:

> I've *just* tried to send you the money but it hasn't worked.

Adding "just" makes it right, **without it you should just use the simple past.**

---

If you are using a machine not working properly you could say:

> **I've *just*** tried to send you the money but the machine isn't working

---

If you are still trying you could say:

> **I'm trying** to send you the money, but the website appears to be broken.

---

If you tried many times, until now, you could say:

> **I've been trying** to send you the money since this morning , but the website is dead.